# Matlab cannot recognize other UIControls of the same fig in callBack functions

Tags: matlab, callback, uicontrol

Here is the code for converting a decimal number to the target number system:

```
    hf = figure('Color', [1, 1, 0], 'Position', [400 400 600 400], ...
  'Name', 'Number System Conversion', 'NumberTitle', 'off', 'MenuBar', 'none');
    uicontrol(hf, 'Style', 'Text', 'Units', 'normalized', ...
  'Position', [0.05, 0.8, 0.45, 0.1], 'HorizontalAlignment', 'center', ...
  'String', 'Input', 'BackgroundColor', [0, 1, 1]);
    uicontrol(hf, 'Style', 'Text', 'Units', 'normalized', ...
  'Position', [0.5, 0.8, 0.45, 0.1], 'HorizontalAlignment', 'center', ...
  'String', 'Output', 'BackgroundColor', [0, 1, 1]);
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    uiinput = uipanel(hf, 'Position', [0.04, 0.33, 0.45, 0.45], ...
  'Units', 'normalized', 'BackgroundColor', [1, 1, 0]);
    uicontrol('Parent', uiinput, 'Style', 'Text', 'Units', 'normalized', ...
  'Position', [0.1, 0.65, 0.25, 0.1], 'HorizontalAlignment', 'right', ...
  'String', 'Decimal', 'BackgroundColor', [1, 1, 0]);
    uicontrol('Parent', uiinput, 'Style', 'Text', 'Units', 'normalized', ...
  'Position', [0.1, 0.25, 0.25, 0.1], 'HorizontalAlignment', 'right', ...
  'String', 'Target Number System', 'BackgroundColor', [1, 1, 0]);
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    he1 = uicontrol(hf, 'Style', 'Edit', 'Units', 'normalized', ...
  'Position', [0.25, 0.6, 0.2, 0.1], 'BackgroundColor', [0, 1, 0]);
    he2 = uicontrol(hf, 'Style', 'Edit', 'Units', 'normalized', ...
  'Position', [0.25, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1], 'BackgroundColor', [0, 1, 0]);
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    uioutput = uipanel(hf, 'Units', 'normalized', ...
  'Position', [0.52, 0.33, 0.45, 0.45], 'BackgroundColor', [1, 1, 0]);
    uicontrol(uioutput, 'Style', 'Text', 'Units', 'normalized', ...
  'Position', [0.1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1], 'HorizontalAlignment', 'left', ...
  'String', 'Result', 'BackgroundColor', [1, 1, 0]);
    ht = uicontrol('Parent', uioutput, 'Style', 'Text', 'Units', 'normalized', ...
  'Position', [0.4, 0.5, 0.4, 0.1], 'HorizontalAlignment', 'center', 'BackgroundColor', [0, 1, 0]);
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    uicontrol(hf, 'Style', 'pushbutton', 'Units', 'normalized', ...
  'Position', [0.18, 0.1, 0.2, 0.12], 'String', 'Convert', 'CallBack', @callBackFun);
    uicontrol(hf, 'Style', 'pushbutton', 'Units', 'normalized', ...
  'Position', [0.65, 0.1, 0.2, 0.12], 'String', 'Exit', 'CallBack', 'close(hf)');
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    function callBackFun(src, event)
        n = str2num(get(he1, 'String'));
        b = str2num(get(he2, 'String'));
        if b >= 10
            warndlg('Target system cannot be larger than 10!', 'Warning');
            set(he2, 'String', '');
        else
            set(ht, 'String', num2str(NumSysConv(n, b)));
        end
    end
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    function NumSysConv = NumSysConv(n, b)
        ch1 = '0123456789';
        k = 1;
        while n ~= 0
            p(k) = rem(n, b);
            n = fix(n/b);
            k = k + 1;
        end
        k = k - 1;
        strdec = '';
        while k >= 1
            kb = p(k);
            strdec = strcat(strdec, ch1(kb + 1: kb + 1));
            k = k - 1;
        end
        NumSysConv = strdec;
    end
```

The problem is in the second from last uicontrol whose callback function is @CallBackFun, in which I want to read and set properties of other uicontrols in the same piece of code, however it renders out the error message: "Undefined function or variable 'he1'.", which means it cannot recognize the uicontrols in the same fig, how to solve this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It can't recognize it because you're not passing the handles to your callback. See: [Share Data Among Callbacks](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/share-data-among-callbacks.html) for methods to pass or retrieve these handles.

Comment: Issue solved by defining 'Tag' in the controls to be visited, and visiting them by findobj('Tag', 'tag_name'), Thank you very much for your comment!